# Google Map Javascript API vs Web Service API

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services, google-maps

I am starting a new project, where admin area allow user to place markers on site each pointing to a seperate location address, the address comes from the database, now I am new to Google maps, I backend developer so more comfortable working with Google map web service API but I can find all samples and examples are for he Javascript API

Which one I should use? google map web service api or javascript API

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) This is a site where users ask specific programming questions and others provide specific solutions. Questions like yours are highly subjective and are not a good fit for this site. I suggest trying out both APIs and deciding on your own which one best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to display maps and have users modify the markers, you will have to use the maps javascript API (js is required to display the maps and can also do geocoding).

Javascript documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Javascript Geocoding Example:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Draggable Marker:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations

The **web services API** is directed more to getting specific information such as geocoding, getting directions and places etc. However if you are already using the javascript front-end of Google maps you might as well use the geocoding services available there, it is easy to use and won't require writing extra code to do the work for you.

Web services documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Javascript API** if you need to use google map features in the browser. For example you want to display a Google Maps image with an icon.

Use the **web service** api if you want your server-side code to have access to google map features, not necessarily for immediate display to the user. For example you want to obtain the distance between two coordinates and store that in a database.

**Javascript API** -> Directly for display to the user

**Web Service API** -> Directly for display to the server side, and then possibly to the user as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on all intents and purposes what you want to do. If you need static maps returned with custom overlays done in an easy fashion, I'd suggest using their web service/REST API.  You can just simply pass the address text into the REST API and it'll return an image of the actual map and you an pass all the different parameters like image width and height you want returned on the screen. You can place markers, and set the zoom level, as well as control whether you want atlas or satellite view with all the respective labels and markers. You can do the same in Javascript, but REST is super easy to utilize and implement.

The static maps API sample:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false